# What is the correct way to use maxBytesPerTrigger in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark readStream and setting option maxBytesPerTrigger like this: `temp_data = spark.readStream.format("delta").option("maxBytesPerTrigger",1000).load(raw_data_delta_table)`
But my whole file is loaded in single batch. I want to load it into multiple batches. Where I'm missing out? And yeah, If I use maxFilesPerTrigger, then it's working fine. But maxBytesPerTrigger is not working.
Thanks

Comment: are you using `.trigger(once=True)` ?

Comment: No, I'm not specifying any trigger

Comment: it is a soft maxium.

Comment: Soft maximum means it will approximately load that much amount of data..Right? But in my case the file size is 10 MB and I'm specifying maxBytesPerTrigger of 1000 Bytes ,i.e., 1 KB...but its loading whole file in single batch

Answer (score 1):

Spark will need to read in the entire file, not pieces of a file. Therefore based off that if the soft max is usually less than the file size then it will ingest the entire file.

See "Limit Input Rate" Section in link below.

https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-streaming.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the behavior of `maxBytesPerTrigger` from delta official [page](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-streaming.html#limit-input-rate).
`maxBytesPerTrigger`: How much data gets processed in each micro-batch. This option sets a “soft max”, meaning that a batch processes approximately this amount of data and may process more than the limit. If you use Trigger.Once for your streaming, this option is ignored. This is not set by default.